How to make a rectangle change position after hitting a certain coordinate
i am new to programming and i am trying to get a rectangle to loop to the to top after it goes off screen, i tried a few thing but, i am stuck. Any help will be much appreciated.
import pygame
pygame.init()
import sys

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((950, 600))
clock = pygame.display.Clock()

spike = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)

while True:
    for event.type in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit

    screen.fill(('black'))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'green' spike)

    spike.y += 5

    if spike.y == -50:
        spike.y = 0


Welcome, can you try updating the if spike.y == -50 to if spike.y == 50?
Also if you still have a problem, i recommend you to print(spike.y) after incrementing it.

I wouldn't test if it equals, I would use <= to ensure the loop, even if the object moves lower than -50.  if spike.y <= -50
